# MongoDB: How to add a hashfield which automatically updates with new hash of document whenever data changes?

Tags: mongodb

The title of this question is the entire question already:

Is there a way to add a field to a MongoDB document that automatically updates with the new hash of the documents whenever the internal data of this document changes? `_id` can't be used for this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongo doesn't have built in triggers.

They recently-ish launched [mongo stitch](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/triggers/database-triggers/) a BaaS of theirs that has trigger support (i'm not sure to what extend as i personally don't use it).

With that said ALL database changes that happen in the mongo are logged into a log file, if you want to create a custom parser you could listen to change in that log and identify the changes you need, however this might approach be overkill for your purposes.